# remove multi-lines in text

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

How do I remove line 1,2,3 and retain line 4?

Like:

1. Programmer
2. Business Owner
3. Manager
4. Marketer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split on linebreaks (\r and \n), then grab the last element:

```
textfield.text = textfield.text.split(/[\r\n]/gm).pop();
```